# Delphi image controls refreshing

Tags: delphi, optimization, graphics, delphi-xe, firemonkey

I'm writing an app for android, but i have some problems with optimization. When Updating positions of 500 TImage ( (fmx controls) the app begin lag. I tried to change my code in procedure from:

```
ImageNum[id].Position.x := newX;
ImageNum[id].Position.x := newY;
```

To:

```
buffPos := TPosition.Create(PointF(newX, newY));
ImageNum[id].Position := buffPos;
buffPos.Free;
```

And from 110 ms (9 fps), new optimization decrease it to 85 ms (11-12 fps). Good, but i need 30 fps. So, i think that the problem is that when i change position of 1 control it is update all form canvas. But how to change position of 500 TImage controls without updating and in the end update all with minimum lag?

Comment: Why continuously create/free the `TPosition`? Why not keep it instantiated and reuse it for all?

Comment: I'm also wondering what you mean by "frames per second". Are you attempting to use these controls to perform some sort of video or animation? As far as we can tell, your lag is somewhere else in your code which we cannot see.

Comment: It gives me small optimization. But i will change it, ok :)

Comment: Animation. About another code: it's code to compute positions of TImage, it's very fast. But on windows i haven't this problem (even on 2000 TImages)

Comment: I wouldn't recommend using hundreds of image controls to mimic an animation. How powerful is your Windows machine? Have you tested it on a less powerful one?

Comment: 2 cores 2.4 Ghz, gt630m. I really want to have 1000 TImage on android (snapdragon 801, adreno 330), 2000 was just a test on windows. I think the small problem in not powerful videocard on my phone. But i think that the real problem in updating form after every change of TImage visual properties (scale, position, angle) instead of 1 form update only after 500 Timages changes. I thinked about to change graphic system: not to update every control. Just create bitmap and draw on it all bitmaps instead of Timages . But is it will faster? Cannot test it now :c

Comment: If you are going to use `TImage` controls, then at least call [`BeginUpdate()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/FMX.Controls.TControl.BeginUpdate) on the parent control before updating the positions, then call [`EndUpdate()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/FMX.Controls.TControl.EndUpdate) when finished.

Comment: But I agree with JerryDodge, using hundreds of `TImage` controls is not the best choice. You should consider using a single [`TPaintBox`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/FMX.Objects.TPaintBox) instead, drawing all of your "images" on its `Canvas` in its `OnPaint` event as needed. When you want to move an "image", simply invalidate the `TPaintBox` to trigger a new `OnPaint` event and then re-draw the "image" in its new position as needed.

Comment: I use begin/endupdate on Timages, it's give -5 ms, good, but not very well. I will try begin/endupdate on parent, ok. And anothet question: is paintbox supports scale and rotations properties of tbitmaps? (i never used a paintbox)

Comment: Simple answer is you throw away all the image controls. Paint each frame to an off screen bitmap and blit that onto the canvas. This will yield orders of magnitude improvement.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I tried to do this. When I rotate around 1000 Images it takes a lot of time (even on Win) (3 fps) (I use TBitMap.Rotate). But without rotating fps around 60. With TImage controls it's faster.

Comment: We can only guess at what you are doing.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan probably i find problem (or not?). When i set GlobalUseGPUCanvas = true, FPS with 500 units ~ 17-20, but if GlobalUseGPUCanvas = false, FPS with 500 units ~ 17-20. ???